# Does user `ubuntu` exist by default on Ubuntu

Tags: users

Is `ubuntu` user with group `1000:1000` standard on an Ubuntu distribution? We are trying to determine whether this user exists as I have seen it on some containers but not on a baremetal server one of the cloud providers provisoned.

Comment: It'll depend on the installed system; I'd not expect a `ubuntu` user on installs I perform but your question is vague without specifics (desktop? core server? server? ie. product specifics, let alone release details that can influence effects)

Comment: In some containers and some pre-made VMs yes, it does. Not on an installed system.

Comment: BTW, Markdown won't work in titles, only in the question body (and comments and answers), so you can remove the ` marks from the title. Also, @guiverc that looks like an answer    :)

Comment: Note that the UID:GID of `ubuntu` is `1000:1000`. Therefore, it was the first non-system user created on the system. On a "normal" installation, `1000:1000` is the user-specified first user, and is a member of the `sudo` group. Is `ubuntu`?  I'm `1000:1000` on all my Ubuntu boxes. Read `man adduser adduser.conf`. The `ubuntu` userid was added somewhere else, not in a standard Ubuntu. `getent passwd ubuntu` to see a little more info.

Comment: The ubuntu user with uid=1000 gid=1000 exists on the live disk, but not usually in the installed system unless that is what was specified for the first account to create.

Comment: Live and persistent live Ubuntu systems have the default user 'ubuntu' with the UID=999.

Answer (score 9):

During the bare-metal install process, you are asked to create a user, so an "Ubuntu" user account is not necessary or desirable.

But a Cloud, Container, Pi, and Live images are pre-made -- you aren't offered the opportunity to create a user. So those images have a default "Ubuntu" user account so you can login.

The "Ubuntu" user is not required for Cloud or Container tasks. There's nothing special about the account, and it's easy enough to make real users once you have access. So some providers or end-users may delete the Ubuntu account in their own images or during provisioning. Or some admins may replace the user during their own setup.

- For example, if you specify a user in `cloud-init`, that user will replace the Ubuntu user.

Comment: You could add that UID 1000 is (as far as I can tell) always either the preinstalled non-root user, or the non-root user added during installation.

Comment: While true in most cases, @sudodus has identified a case (Live media) where the user 'Ubuntu' has UID=999 instead of UID=1000. There may be other corner cases out there. If the UID matters --like setting up remote mounts-- then double-checking the UID seems wise anyway.